# Can functions be default parameter values?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin docs states that "functions are first-class". I'm trying to use a function as a default value of a function extension. However the compiler isn't having any of it:

```
fun <T> identity(x: T): T = x
fun <T, P> Channel<T>.dedupe(by: (T) -> P = ::identity): ReceiveChannel<T>
{
    ...
}
```

The error is `Function invocation 'identity(...)' expected` which kinda indicates Kotlin isn't really understanding what I want to do at all.

Is there a way?

Comment: I'd change parameter name since `by` is a keyword for delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you get this error message, but the problem is type mismatch: the default value must make sense for any type parameters (subject to bounds). I.e. you need a `(T) -> P`, but `::identity` can give you `(T) -> T` or `(P) -> P`.

Proof: if you change to

```
fun <T, P> identity(x: T): P = throw Exception()
fun <T, P> List<T>.dedupe(by: (T) -> P = ::identity): Unit {}
```

it compiles.

### Answer (which came out in comments below):

If `P` is changed to `Any?`, we should be able to use `::identity` because `(T) -> T` is a subtype of `(T) -> Any?`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, but using a lambda instead of a function reference does:

```
fun <T> identity(x: T): T = x
fun <T> Channel<T>.dedupe(by: (T) -> Any? = { it }): ReceiveChannel<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good point! What if I want to make it understand `(T) -> T` actually can fulfill `(T) -> P`? ... I guess I can change `by: (T) -> Any?` but `::ident` would still not fulfill it?

Comment: Well, it can't. E.g. for `T = String, P = Int`. This is the same as trying `fun <T> (x: T = 0): T = x`; hopefully it's clear why that shouldn't compile?

Comment: For `(T) -> Any?` it's surprising that `::identity` doesn't work, it seems to me that it should by covariance. But `{ identity(it) }` does.

Comment: Yes. That's clear. If we go back to what I'm trying to solve: I want a `dedupe` function that optionally takes an "extractor" function argument. If the extractor function isn't provided, elements are deduped by simple equality. If the extractor is provided, each element is "transformed" to some unspecified type and that is used for equality.

Comment: Or, well, just `{ it }` :)